# Following functionality - database design problem - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

I need following functionality in my app (twitter like). One user can fallow other user.
I have model User, and I tried with self many-to-many relation, but I don't know how to implement this in my model.

Can you explain me some example how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michael Hartl's tutorial has an entire section on follower relationships. I recommend reading it to get a better understanding of self many-to-many relations. It helped me a lot:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users

You could also use a gem like `acts_as_follower`, which abstracts much of the design details out for you:

https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower